# Children arguments when using :simple_one_for_one strategy

Tags: elixir

When using the `:simple_one_for_one` strategy, we specify the children to launch dynamically:

```
supervise([worker(FooServer, [])], strategy: :simple_one_for_one)
```

We then use something like the following to start children:

```
def start_child(arg1, arg2) do
  Supervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, [arg1, arg2])
end
```

The [documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Supervisor.html#start_child/2) states (emphasis mine):

> In the case of :simple_one_for_one, the child specification defined in the supervisor will be used and instead of a child_spec, an arbitrary list of terms is expected. The child process ***will then be started by appending the given list to the existing function arguments in the child specification***.

I tried the following

```
supervise([worker(FooServer, [:foo])], strategy: :simple_one_for_one)
#                             ^^^^
#                             "fixed" argument
```

But it seems arguments aren't appended, and I can't find how to access these fixed arguments. Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the following code in iex:

```
defmodule Child do
  def start_link(arg, arg2) do
    IO.inspect(arg)
    IO.inspect(arg2)

    pid = spawn fn() ->
      receive do
        _any -> arg
      end
    end

    {:ok, pid}
  end
end

defmodule Sup do
  use Supervisor

  def start_link do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(_args) do
    children = [
      worker(Child, [:arg], restart: :transient)
    ]

    supervise(children, strategy: :simple_one_for_one)
  end

  def start_child do
    Supervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, [:arg2])
  end
end
```

Here's the behavior I got:

```
iex(1)> Supervisor.start_link
  {:ok, #PID<xxxxx>}
iex(2)> Supervisor.start_child
  :arg
  :arg2
  {:ok, #PID<0.69.0>}
```

So it looks like it's working correctly for me. It's difficult to offer advice on what's happening in your code without being able to see your code, but perhaps your expectation is that your argument is a list of args, when instead you're receiving each of the args as separate parameters.